# How would I say this in the reverse?

Tags: technical-writing, business-writing

I am sending out a message to all users that have filed a bug report for my last game; the one I shut the server down on.  The broadcast message I am sending is going to be an email, but I'm not entirely sure how to word it.

I know normally there'd be something like...

> It is my displeasure to inform you that the  game servers have been shut down indefinitely, and updates for this series have been terminated.

However, "it is my displeasure" is obviously the wrong thing to say here.  What would I use in place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what you meant about saying this "in reverse", but possible variations:

"It is with regret that I have to inform you ..."

"It is with great sadness that I have to inform you ..."

"I'm sorry to have to let you know ..."